# tezos-baker error Did not find service via RPC

Tags: node, tezos-client, baker, upgrade

After importing a snapshot to try and solve a different error (see [here](https://tezos-baking.slack.com/archives/CB8K1F7TR/p1663320790021119) in the tezos baking slack) I have encountered this new error.

```
Sep 17 12:41:18 raspberrypi tezos-baker-013-PtJakart[63965]: Sep 17 12:41:18.418 - 013-PtJakart.baker.rpc:     Did not find service: GET http://localhost:8732/chains/main/blocks/BLR2RyzpZL7oTNMZ12BAsaUKqKswCVN2misoCCuu6zBMrZkcWW7/protocols
Sep 17 12:41:18 raspberrypi tezos-baker-013-PtJakart[63965]: Sep 17 12:41:18.418 - 013-PtJakart.baker.rpc:
Sep 17 12:41:49 raspberrypi tezos-baker-013-PtJakart[63965]: Sep 17 12:41:49.279 - 013-PtJakart.baker.rpc: error while monitoring heads
Sep 17 12:41:49 raspberrypi tezos-baker-013-PtJakart[63965]: Sep 17 12:41:49.279 - 013-PtJakart.baker.rpc:   Error:
Sep 17 12:41:49 raspberrypi tezos-baker-013-PtJakart[63965]: Sep 17 12:41:49.279 - 013-PtJakart.baker.rpc:     Did not find service: GET http://localhost:8732/chains/main/blocks/BMVhLgeymHs6WJsKZUG2SHTyyyEwp2ppiTkuSwPMSLfcLzHQKVZ/protocols
Sep 17 12:41:49 raspberrypi tezos-baker-013-PtJakart[63965]: Sep 17 12:41:49.279 - 013-PtJakart.baker.rpc:
Sep 17 12:42:18 raspberrypi tezos-baker-013-PtJakart[63965]: Sep 17 12:42:18.982 - 013-PtJakart.baker.rpc: error while monitoring heads
Sep 17 12:42:18 raspberrypi tezos-baker-013-PtJakart[63965]: Sep 17 12:42:18.982 - 013-PtJakart.baker.rpc:   Error:
Sep 17 12:42:18 raspberrypi tezos-baker-013-PtJakart[63965]: Sep 17 12:42:18.982 - 013-PtJakart.baker.rpc:     Did not find service: GET http://localhost:8732/chains/main/blocks/BLpaCJ28P5qsLFaCbmc5Eg7YuaMuW5xfZcuD9R8EPexBzL6sgPA/protocols
Sep 17 12:42:18 raspberrypi tezos-baker-013-PtJakart[63965]: Sep 17 12:42:18.983 - 013-PtJakart.baker.rpc:
Sep 17 12:42:48 raspberrypi tezos-baker-013-PtJakart[63965]: Sep 17 12:42:48.457 - 013-PtJakart.baker.rpc: error while monitoring heads
Sep 17 12:42:48 raspberrypi tezos-baker-013-PtJakart[63965]: Sep 17 12:42:48.457 - 013-PtJakart.baker.rpc:   Error:
Sep 17 12:42:48 raspberrypi tezos-baker-013-PtJakart[63965]: Sep 17 12:42:48.457 - 013-PtJakart.baker.rpc:     Did not find service: GET http://localhost:8732/chains/main/blocks/BLzrVPKhtb5nQFQejF4DLE1fkR7Dm8EXxFfDLephB4yDF1LS7ec/protocols
Sep 17 12:42:48 raspberrypi tezos-baker-013-PtJakart[63965]: Sep 17 12:42:48.457 - 013-PtJakart.baker.rpc:
```

However the accuser is started and the node is bootstrapped with neither of them giving an error (shown in the first image in the same terminal as the print of the error above).

I ran:  `./tezos-client rpc get /chains/main/blocks/head/metadata` to see if it even recognizes the chain and I’m getting fatal error: `No service found at this URL`  (Found in 2nd image).

The tezos node seems to be running fine and its bootstrapped. (see 3rd image, note that the printout has different block hashes as I restarted the node to see if that would work unfortunately it didn’t).

[image]
[image]
[image]

Bakery has already been down since Friday. Any help would be greatly appreciated. [Here](https://tezos-baking.slack.com/archives/CB8K1F7TR/p1663418293173409?thread_ts=1663320790.021119&cid=CB8K1F7TR) is the post I did in the #errors channel in the Tezos Bakers slack

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: We are looking into issues with xtz-shots snapshots. Can you try a snapshot from https://snapshots-tezos.giganode.io/ ?

Comment: Will do, i'll update here when I have a result

Comment: @nicolasochem it was the xtz-shots snapshot. Works with the giganode . Thanks so much!

Comment: @nicolasochem since this solved the problem, do you want to add some details + links to an answer below, so that it can be marked top answer and the question closed